# Android Share intent not loading images

Tags: android, android-intent

When I try to share an image in facebook using intent getting the message `"Sorry we couldn't load your photo"`

I'm using the following code,

```
         Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/drawable/"+filename);
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         intent.setType("image/jpg");
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);             
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));
```

When I tried to send via gmail, getting no attachment. 
May I know what is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Some application(like Gmail, Facebook, Google Plus ...) can't get photo to attach,   because your *imageUri*  is private.

You should save your drawable to gallery or public folder, then get newImageUri to share.
    `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, newImageUri);`

Comment: Yes, I understood that, and done in the same way. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void shareImage()
{
Bitmap icon = mBitmap;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));


}
```